# Alphabet Bucket 2

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hoops(ArrayList<String> a) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(26);
    
    for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
        list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    
    for (int y = 0; y < a.size(); y++) {
        for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
            if (String.valueOf(x).equals(a.get(y).substring(0, 1))) {
                list.get(x - 97).add(a.get(y));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return list;
}
```

This is code meant to "Write and test a method that takes a List words, which contains Strings of alphabetic characters, throws them into 26 "buckets", according to the first letter, and returns the ArrayList of buckets. Each bucket should be represented by an ArrayList. The first bucket should contain all the Strings from words that start with an 'a', in the same order as they appear in words; the second bucket should contain all the Strings that start with a 'b'; and so on. Your method should traverse the list words only once and leave it unchanged."

When I run the following code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("cat", "dog", "person", "beetle", "insect"));
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 0, 1, 3));
    
    System.out.print(hoops(a).get('a'));
}
```

I get an error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 97, Size: 26
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
at marcoB.Reverse.main(Reverse.java:13)
```

How can I fix this?

PS. I just asked a question similar to this but I edited my code and implemented x - 97

Answer (score 0):

An 'IndexOutOfBoundsException' occurs when you try to reference or "get" a value at an index of the array that it doesn't have. You are seeing 97 come up in the error message because of this line in your main method:

```
System.out.print(hoops(a).get('a'));
```

'a' in this case turns into it's ASCII value of 97 (see http://www.asciitable.com/ for more), which is out of the range of the ArrayList you are referencing (26). So either do a `get(0)` or a `get('a'-97)` if you want to keep the rest of your implementation the same and get the list which contains the 'a' characters.

There are definitely fancier ways to go about printing the list at a certain character if you go deeper into this.

I would also suggest making your variable names more meaningful in your loops. For example, changing `x` to `letter` and `y` to `word` might be easier for you to keep track of rather than x and y, especially when you start working with more complicated looping structures.

Comment: Thanks so much. Makes much more sense now.